# Magento custom module get details from backend

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem in getting the data from the backend so i can show it up in my controller.

For example I have this module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module

in **config.xml** i will add a **routers** for the **controllers**

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <custompay>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>CompanyName_NewModule</module>
                <frontName>newmodule</frontName>
            </args>
        </custompay>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Controller (**CompanyName/NewModule/controllers/IndexController.php**)

```
class CompanyName_NewModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    protected $_order;

    public function getOrder() {
        if ($this->_order == null) {

        }
        return $this->_order;
    }

    public function indexAction(){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
        $session->setCompanyNameNewModuleQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('newmodule/redirect')->toHtml());
        $session->unsQuoteId();
        $session->unsRedirectUrl();
    }

}
```

Block (**CompanyName/NewModule/Block/Redirect.php**)

```
class CompanyName_NewModule_Block_Redirect extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract {

    protected function _toHtml() {
        $html = '<html><body>';
        $html.= $this->__('You will be redirected to the payment website in a few seconds.');
        $html.= '</body></html>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem. I don't have an idea on how i can get the details from the backend and i will use it in the **redirect.php** block. And how I can get the product details that the customer want to purchase.

I know that I need to include the model so I can get the details and when I print_r this

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
```

I don't see any product details.

Please share some knowledge or links. Your help will be a big contribution to magento developer beginners. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$products = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

Check this article for more:- [Magento: Get all shopping cart items and totals](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-all-shopping-cart-items-and-totals/)

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something similar in your block to get the quote and used payment method instance

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

//to assure that you don't initiate a new instance with Mage::getModel('yourextension/model'); and always use the same instance 
$paymentMethod = $quote->getPayment()->getMethodInstance(); 

//assuming that this is implemented and returns Mage::getStoreConfig('your/config/path');
$paymentMethodConfig = $paymentMethod()->getConfig();

$products = $quote->getAllItems();
```